# What are these small, round, red berries covered with bumps, on low-growing plants in Upstate New York?

Tags: identification, fruits, strawberries

I found these bumpy red berries on low-growing plants growing wild in my lawn. They look kind of like wild strawberries, but they are rounder with more pronounced bumps. Do you have any ideas as to the species and edibility? These grew in summer, in Upstate New York State.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They look like [mock strawberries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_strawberry). *Duchesnea indica*. They are edible (if they are truly mock strawberries), but not as tasty as real strawberries.

Comment: (if they are not mock mock strawberries!)

Comment: Apparently not toxic, but not tasty either. https://dobianchi.com/2015/05/11/mock-strawberry-poisonous/

Answer (score 0):

This is a plant Cinquefoil.
Family of the strawberry.

Comment: The Cinquefoil I know is not a ground creeper, but a vine growing up trees and turning scarlet in Fall. It has pea-sized navy blue round berries.

Comment: HI Bee-Pie, are you able to edit your answer and provide a photo or  a link to substantiate your answer.